# Image Not Found Using HTML/Django

Tags: html, django, image

Django cant find jpg. It is in the same folder as my html. Tried everything i could, I have no idea why this is happening. I am using index.html. Tried different files, different file paths, different file types...etc. File isnt corrupted, program works fine for everything else.

[File Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OarmU.png)

```
<div>
  <img src="portBack.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Django handles static files in a different way. You can't put url directly in the file.

Firat of all you need to save you image file inside the static folder in the app.
After that you need add following line in settings.py file.

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

And following in html file.
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">

For more information, please check official documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/